# WordPress user functionally created successfully but 'SB Welcome Email' not sent

Tags: php, wordpress, email, notifications

I have created wp user by functions and it's working successfully. Now the problem is `SB Welcome Email` not sent if the user created by function but If I created manually user from dashboard then mail has been sent. I don't want to use another custom wp_mail() for custom user creation by functions. How can I overcome this? [SB Welcome Email Code](https://github.com/timstl/SB-Welcome-Email-Editor/blob/master/sb_welcome_email_editor.php)

```
$user_login     =  wp_slash( $username );
    $user_email     =  wp_slash( $email );
    $display_name   =  wp_slash( $full_name );
    $first_name     =  wp_slash( $f_name );
    $last_name      =  wp_slash( $l_name );
    $user_pass      =  $password;
    $role           =  'student';
    $exists = email_exists( $user_email );

    if ( username_exists( $user_login ) && !email_exists( $user_email ) ) {
        $user_login = $user_login.'_student';
    } else {
        $user_login = $user_login;
    }


    if ( !$exists ) {
        $userdata = compact( 'user_login', 'user_email', 'user_pass', 'display_name', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'role' );
        //return wp_insert_user( $userdata );
        $user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata ) ;

    }else{
        $user   = get_user_by( 'email', $user_email );
        $user_id = $user->ID;
    }
```

Comment: `sb_we_send_new_user_notification` function need to call on hook. Please avoid calling this function directly.

Comment: Please find the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are missing a hook that is used by this 'SB Welcome Email' plugin.

The one hook I can think of is `user_register` ([documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register)). But by default it is part from the `wp_insert_user` ([documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_user/)), so it should be triggered when you add the new user. In this case you should check the 'SB Welcome Email' code and search for that functionality that sends the actual code and see if there isn't some other hook that the plugin is using.

Comment: Hi, Could you define which hook I have to use? I have added the GitHub link. Thanks!

Comment: The only think I see is that they use `wpmu_welcome_user_notification` filter, so I guess you also have some of the WPMU plugins. So what I would do in this case is to use the send email function they are using for this filter. In this case this is: `sb_we_mu_new_user_notification` which is actually calling `wp_new_user_notification($user_id, null, 'both');`. So include this last function in your code were the user is created and pass the `$user_id` to it. Don't forget to check if this function exists before using it as if  the SB plugin is disabled it will create a fatal error.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this. Need to use this functions `wp_new_user_notification($user_ids, false, 'both')`

Comment: Dont use directly. Please check my answer, hope that work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The function `sb_we_send_new_user_notification` will be called once the user created. This action hook allows call a function for a new user immediately after they are added to the database. The user id is passed to hook as an argument.

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 10, 1 );

function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id ) {

    sb_we_send_new_user_notification($user_id, true, true);

}
```